# Long response time Cypress

Tags: node.js, angular, cypress

It happens that I am writing a test in Cypress, but i need to know how cypress could wait until the Backend timeout, since there can be a process that lasts up to two hours, I have tried with cy.wait with cy.intercept, but it waits a maximum of 30 seconds, but in this case It is not for time, but until the Backend returns a response.

Comment: Are you sure that you want your Cypress test to wait for up to 2 hours ? Cypress is usually to test your UI so that you check that it is behaving as expected. What about mocking your backend to simulate the work that your backend does?

Comment: Thanks for responding, at this moment I am not using a mocking, because although I wrote about the time of two hours, what I am referring to is a time that I do not know that the backend will respond, this for database processes, and these processes will respond to me with information that I need to put on the screen

Answer (score 0):

You can use aliases to make Cypress wait for a specific network call.

```js
cy.intercept('/foo').as('myRequest');
cy.wait('@myRequest');
```

If you're already doing that, and it is only waiting a maximum of 30 seconds, that is most likely because your global `requestTimeout` value is set at 30 seconds (`30000`). You can override this as the suite level or an individual command level.

```js
// global change
// cypress.config.js
...
e2e: {
  ...
  requestTimeout: 60000,
  ...
}
...
// specific command level
cy.wait('@myRequest', { requestTimeout: 60000 });
```

With all of that being said, having your test run for up to two hours is definitely an anti-pattern, and I would look into mocking out those responses so that your tests are not dependent on that data.

Comment: Thank you for responding, what I am referring to is a time that I do not know that the backend will respond, this is due to database processes, and these processes respond to me with information that I need to place on the screen, in this case, what time will the optimal for modifying the Cypress timeout?

Comment: Ideally, your backend can respond in a _reasonable_ amount of time -- what that is I can't say for certain. How long _should_ the backend take to respond (regardless of automation)? If a user tried to use the website, how long would you expect them to wait for an answer? On projects I've worked on, we usually define a timeout as 10s for network calls in lower environments, but again, there have been times I've gone higher, and times I've gone lower.

Comment: With that -- setting something at a minute can easily cause your test time to balloon -- every network request can take _up to a minute_.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I understand what you are saying, in this case I have two critical points, the first is due to queries that include heavy views, the second is procedures that also respond in a long period of time, so, the best Would it be to simulate consultations or procedures that take more than a minute?